# Meaning of the Notation f ∈ F[0, 1]?

Tags: functions, notation

I would like to know what the notation F[0,1] represents. I tried searching "F[0,1]" on google but the symbols makes it hard for relevant results to come up.

It appeared like this on my homework:

```
Let V = {f ∈ F[0, 1]|f(0) = f(1) = 0}
```

My guess is that the x in f(x) is on the closed interval [0,1]. Could someone confirm this for me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume this means $V$ is the set of functions that are continuous on [0,1], and that satisfy the conditions $f(0) = f(1) = 0$.